# Surround on tex files

Tags: plugin-vimtex, plugin-vim-surround

I have both vimtex and surround plugins installed(and ultisnip if matters). 
When doing surround in visual mode (using `S`) on a tex file, and when I press `\` next I get immediately `\begin`. I am not sure how to change this.
I want to surround by `\{` sometimes.

(`S` in visual mode mapped to `<plug>VSurround`)

Comment: I'm not sure but this might be helpful https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/af0d4ae2580f75d730b9412f37431f746abcb5a9/doc/vimtex.txt#L3882

Comment: Yeh, obviously I had already looked at this. No real explanations there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is from vim-surround. From its [source code](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim#L212), pressing either `l` or `\` will result in `\begin`.

To change the default behavior, refer to `:h surround-customizing`.

- First, find the number corresponding to `\`. In this case, we would find it with `:echo char2nr("\\")`, which gives `92`.
- Then, declare the variable corresponding to this number. In this case, this would be

```
let g:surround_92 = "\\{ \r \\}"
```

If you prefer not to have a space betweeen the surroundings and the surrounded text, use

```
let g:surround_92 = "\\{\r\\}"
```

In the above, `\r` is the placeholder for the surrounded text.
Note that since our surroundings contain `\`, we have to escape it by doubling the backslash.
Also, since this is specific to .tex files, it is better to use `b:surround_92` instead of `g:surround_92`.